# Count of function execution in method on code compilation

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to count how many times function 'ExecuteAction' appear in class method.

```
public class A : B
{
  public void X()
  {
    ExecuteAction(....);
    ExecuteAction(....);
  }
}
```

And the score is 2 becouse ExecuteAction appear 2x. I need it becouse I build testing framework and would like allow for external test operator to know where current step execution is and where it will end. Is it possible to do or should I change my approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Some disassembly required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the approach that demonstrates how to read method body via reflection and count all the calls of the specific method:

```
class Foo {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        ExecuteAction();
        ExecuteAction();
    }
    public void ExecuteAction() {
        //
    }
}
// --- Read the IL ---
var mInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("SomeMethod");
var token = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("ExecuteAction").MetadataToken;

var methodBody = mInfo.GetMethodBody();
var rawIL = methodBody.GetILAsByteArray();

int counter = 0;
var reader = new ILReader(rawIL);
while(reader.Read(mInfo)) {
    if(reader.OpCode == OpCodes.Call && object.Equals(reader.MetadataToken, token)) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Method \"{0}\" call detected", reader.Operand);
        counter++;
    }
}
System.Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", counter);
```

The `ILReader` class is implemented as follows(minimal implementation for this specific task) :

```
class ILReader {
    readonly byte[] msil;
    int ptr;
    public ILReader(byte[] msil) {
        this.msil = msil;
    }
    public OpCode OpCode { get; private set; }
    public int MetadataToken { get; private set; }
    public object Operand { get; private set; }
    public bool Read(MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        if(ptr < msil.Length) {
            OpCode = ReadOpCode();
            Operand = ReadOperand(OpCode, methodInfo);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    OpCode ReadOpCode() {
        byte instruction = ReadByte();
        if(instruction != 254)
            return singleByteOpCode[instruction];
        else
            return doubleByteOpCode[ReadByte()];
    }
    object ReadOperand(OpCode code, MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        MetadataToken = 0;
        switch(code.OperandType) {
            case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                MetadataToken = ReadInt();
                System.Type[] methodArgs = null;
                if(methodInfo.GetType() != typeof(ConstructorInfo))
                    methodArgs = methodInfo.GetGenericArguments();
                System.Type[] typeArgs = null;
                if(methodInfo.DeclaringType != null)
                    typeArgs = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments();
                return methodInfo.Module.ResolveMember(MetadataToken, typeArgs, methodArgs);
        }
        return null;
    }
    byte ReadByte() {
        return msil[ptr++];
    }
    int ReadInt() {
        byte b1 = ReadByte();
        byte b2 = ReadByte();
        byte b3 = ReadByte();
        byte b4 = ReadByte();
        return (int)b1 | (((int)b2) << 8) | (((int)b3) << 16) | (((int)b4) << 24);
    }
    #region static
    static ILReader() {
            CreateOpCodes();
        }
    static OpCode[] singleByteOpCode;
    static OpCode[] doubleByteOpCode;
    static void CreateOpCodes() {
        singleByteOpCode = new OpCode[225];
        doubleByteOpCode = new OpCode[31];

        FieldInfo[] fields = GetOpCodeFields();

        for(int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++) {
            OpCode code = (OpCode)fields[i].GetValue(null);
            if(code.OpCodeType == OpCodeType.Nternal)
                continue;

            if(code.Size == 1)
                singleByteOpCode[code.Value] = code;
            else
                doubleByteOpCode[code.Value & 0xff] = code;
        }
    }
    static FieldInfo[] GetOpCodeFields() {
        return typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    }
    #endregion static
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a script that counts the number of times your function appears in your source code?  Something along the lines of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"<filepath>/Program.cs")))
        {
            while (sr.Peek()>0)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains("Function(") 
                    && !(line.Contains("class") || line.Contains("static") || line.Contains("public")))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: hmm... I would need something what run this script before compilation start, change source to place the count of "ExecuteAction(...)" and then...compile source